# Tableau - heat maps - hottest and coldest per column not overall data set

Tags: heatmap, tableau-desktop

I'm trying to create a heat map in Tableau that will show me the hottest and coldest values per field, at the moment it is currently just assessing all values in the data set and assigning heat based on the lowest and highest values, irrespective of where they appear in the data set. Example below:

Place        chickens       bears      potatoes 
a.............              10..........             100......         5000 
b .............             70..........             50......           7000  
c.............              30..........             5........           3000 
d.............              30..........             150........100

In the example table above, I'd like each column to have its own individual heat ranking (e.g. Chickens in place B should be hot, place b cold. Bears in place D should be hot, place C cold etc.). Can this be done in Tableau on one screen? I know if I filter on one column it works, but I'd rather have this all in one visualisation if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See the example below. [image: example]

When you have multiple measures in a viz using the measure names pseudo-field on the color shelf, you can have a separate color legend for each measure name. ***You can choose to have separate or combined color legends by right-clicking on the measure names pill on the color shelf/marks card.***

In the example, I chose to use a different color palette for each measure, but that's not required. You can use the same palette for each legend if you wish, and still get different scales.